# future value with es6 promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'd like to have a `future` value, which can be resolved with value, pending or rejected in a similar manner to scala's future.

```
var username = new Promise();
username.then(x => console.log(x));

// half an hour later, triggered by user click or by ajax, or by timer, or  
username.resolve('john');
```

Is there something built-in for that or would I have to reinvent the bicycle ?

Comment: Found this: 
https://github.com/seangenabe/es6-deferred/blob/master/deferred.js

Comment: So you answered your own question 8 minutes after you posted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deferred.js offers that at https://github.com/seangenabe/es6-deferred/blob/master/deferred.js

```
"use strict";

var Promise = global.Promise || require('es6-promise').Promise;

var Deferred = function() {
  this.promise = new Promise((function(resolve, reject) {
    this.resolve = resolve;
    this.reject = reject;
  }).bind(this));

  this.then = this.promise.then.bind(this.promise);
  this.catch = this.promise.catch.bind(this.promise);
};

module.exports = Deferred;
```

Usage example:

```
var d = new Deferred();
d.then(x => console.log(x));
d.resolve('boo');
```

Comment: Promises have that capability if you save the resolve function somewhere.